# All User ID's , -1001199520004 when bot added to group as admin?

Tags: telegram-bot

Mybot is saving user ID ect. to google sheets and respond ,but when added to a group it saves all user IDs as -1001199520004 and respond with undefined undefined + answer and saves name & surname as undefined undefined aswell.

```
function doPost(e) {
  // this is where telegram works
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var text = data.message.text;
  var id = data.message.chat.id;
  var name = data.message.chat.id.first_name + " " + 
data.message.chatid.last_name;
  var answer = name + ", whatever " ;
  sendText(id,answer);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].appendRow([new 
Date(),id,name,text]);

  if(/^@/.test(text)) {
    var sheetName = text.slice(1).split(" ")[0];
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName) ? 
SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName) : 
SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).insertSheet(sheetName);
    var comment = text.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
    sheet.appendRow([new Date(),id,name,comment,answer]);
  }
}
```